# Can Maya be connected to Yahoo! Calendar via CalDAV?

Tags: calendar

I have attempted to connect Maya to Yahoo! Calendar using the same instructions as for Mozilla Thunderbird with Lightning, but it keeps returning Error 8 (Message Corrupt).

As per an answer given for a different CalDAV provider, I attempted to set it up without the `@yahoo.com` in the userid, but I keep getting the same error message.

Has anyone successfully set this up? It works in Lightning.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, been searching for a solution for a long time and haven't found any. It's silly, considering the fact that the only problem is Evolution server (which is used by Maya, just as Gnome-calendar and California) using wrong URL for Yahoo calendars.
The correct URL is https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com/dav/YOUR_USERNAME/Calendar/YOUR_CALENDARNAME and it's working in Lightning.

on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/729585/impossible-to-sync-yahoo-calendars-with-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I am using the German email service GMX and found that I have to use my **customer number instead of my email adress as a user ID** in Maya! Together with the Thunderbird style url, synchronization works. You might want to try that, if you haven't already. I hope it solves your problem.